# Does the Soundcloud SDK support 64bit?

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I followed the page https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart.

Since now arm64 is required, I changed the:

Architectures: Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)

Build Active Architecture Only: No

Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7

I got errors, so now I am wondering, does the SoundCloud API support 64bit?

Errors are like below:

```
"_NXOAuth2AccountDidFailToGetAccessTokenNotification", referenced from:
-[SCSoundCloud init] in libSoundCloudAPI.a(SCSoundCloud.o)
"_NXOAuth2AccountStoreAccountsDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
-[SCSoundCloud init] in libSoundCloudAPI.a(SCSoundCloud.o)
"_NXOAuth2AccountStoreDidFailToRequestAccessNotification", referenced from:
-[SCSoundCloud init] in libSoundCloudAPI.a(SCSoundCloud.o) 
"_NXOAuth2AccountStoreErrorKey", referenced from:
-[SCLoginViewController failToRequestAccess:] in libSoundCloudUI.a(SCLoginViewController.o)
```

Comment: Show some code, where you are getting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using SoundCloud library as well for a while in my project. Due to is not very up-to-date and it has a lot of dependencies I decided to create my own library and publish it on Github:

[ABMSoundCloudAPI on Github](https://github.com/andresbrun/ABMSoundCloudAPI)

Maybe it could be useful for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue in  Soundcloud of demo project in 64 bits.

I had did lots of googling/R&D and base on that I have got to know below summary.

1) SoundCloud project/libraries was build only for 32bits (Not for 64bits)

2) If you configure sound cloud library in your project and if you are trying to execute for iPhone5s, iPhone5c, iPhone6, iPhone6+ simulator (any Xcode i.e XCODE5.0,5.1,6,6.1) then it gives reference or other error but if you execute in iphone5 or iPhone4s or iPhone4 then it works perfectly with out error.

3) Once Sound clouds library will be updated for 64bits then you need to replace only libraries and it will work without much efforts.

4) If you want demo source code of the application then let me know..I will help you out on that

Comment: I am facing same issue. I will check in my project as per your instruction. thanks

Comment: Ok john try by your self and let me know.